# How to Write code as text in python? or how to use multiple quotations in one string?

Tags: python, c#, pycharm

I'm trying to fix my code in c# with python with the replace element. So this is what I type

```
Sentence = "{My c# code}"
print(Sentence.replace("Console","System.Console"))
```

Because I want to add "System" behind all the Consoles but theres to many to do it manually. but the problem is pycharm thinks is all real code and not string value therefore unable to replace the words. Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Pycharm thinks this is real code". Most text editors that I'm aware of support CTRL + F, select all and replace -- does PyCharm not support this?

Comment: Like when you put stuff in quotations its a string value but when I try to put my c# in there its identified as executive code. I want it as a string value

Answer (score 0):

use triple quotes you can use single or double quotes
Sentence = """{My c# code}"""